# Custom pager view in Slick Grid

Tags: slickgrid

The default pager view in Slick grid looks like this[image]:

Assume that I have the count of total number records, then how to customize slick-pager to show the clickable page numbers depending on the total number of records, so that pager looks something like this.

[image]

Also, how to handle their events?

Answer (score 0):

the `controls/slick.pager.js` file creates the pager along with all its graphic elements, and handles the events too. Customise that.

It's going to be a little tricky though because if you have 1000 pages, you're going to need to cull the middle page numbers down to a maximum of 10 or so...